# How to remove newline characters from csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have the below part of code that reads values from the csv file "prom output.csv" and writes them sorted in a new one "sorted output.csv".

```
import collections
import csv

with open("prom output.csv","r") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    d=collections.defaultdict(lambda : list())
    header=next(cr)   
    for r in cr:
        d[r[0]].append(r[1])  
        

with open("sorted output.csv","w") as f:
    cr = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    cr.writerow(header)  
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
    for k,v in od.items():  s
        cr.writerow([k,",".join(v)])
```

However the output (see below) has spaces between each line and i would like to remove them. Can anybody help?

[image]

The input file "prom output.csv" has no spaces between each line as seen below

[image]

as a last midification i would like my output to look like:

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: not knowing the csv package, I think either the writerow method creates the newline or it is contained in you values which you join for write. In the latter case, you could try to apply the strip() method to remove whitespaces:
`cr.writerow([k,(",".join(v)).strip()]) `

Comment: i tried the strip() method but the output is exactly the same

Comment: Can you please edit with the a minimal example of the file content in code blocks rather than excel screenshots?

Comment: Also, [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39426204/2308683) to your question contained no empty lines in the output

Comment: See Martijn's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39447867/3714940) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447817/write-output-file-in-csv-format-in-python) question

Comment: I would like to do another modification so that each letter appears into a different column. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: You should create new posts for new questions. Comments are meant for clarification on the existing questions

Comment: That might indeed be better. Will do it

Answer (score 1):

apparently changing the line: `cr = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n')`
 into: `cr = csv.writer(f,sys.stdout, lineterminator='\n')` and adding `import sys` to the imports solves the problem.

Comment: "TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument" - You had to run the code in Python 3

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
cr = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
```

to

```
cr = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",", lineterminator='\n')
```

does the trick.

I tried `cr = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')` and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple feasible solution:

```
import collections
import csv

with open('prom output.csv') as f:
    header = next(csv.reader(f))
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    for r in csv.reader(f):
        try:
            d[r[0]] += ','+r[1]
        except:
            d[r[0]] = ','+r[1]

with open('sorted output.csv', 'w') as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerow(header)
    for k, v in d.items():
        f.write(k+v+'\n')
```

For the input of the following CSV file (`prom output.csv`):

```
case,event,startTime,completeTime
101,A
101,B
101,Y
102,C
102,D
102,U
103,A
103,B
103,Y
```

The output was (`sorted output.csv`):

```
case,event,startTime,completeTime
101,A,B,Y
102,C,D,U
103,A,B,Y
```

Which is the output as you intended it to be.