# How to write output file in CSV format in python?

Tags: python, csv

I tried to write output file as a CSV file but getting either an error or not the expected result. I am using Python 3.5.2 and 2.7 also.

Getting error in Python 3.5:

```
wr.writerow(var)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and

In Python 2.7, I am getting all column result in one column.

Expected Result:
An output file same format as the input file.

Code:

```
import csv

f1 = open("input_1.csv", "r") 

resultFile = open("out.csv", "wb")
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, quotechar=',') 

def sort_duplicates(f1):
  for i in range(0, len(f1)):
      f1.insert(f1.index(f1[i])+1, f1[i])
      f1.pop(i+1)

for var in f1:
      #print (var)
      wr.writerow([var])
```

If I am using `resultFile = open("out.csv", "w")`, I get one row extra in the output file.

If I am using above code, getting one row and column extra.

Comment: You're opening the out file in binary mode. Just remove the `b` from the `open("out.csv", "wb")`.

Comment: @Sevanteri: I tried but getting one row is extra in result file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have answered that you should open the output file in text mode when using Python 3, i.e.

```
with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as resultFile:
    ...
```

But you also need to parse the incoming CSV data. As it is your code reads each line of the input CSV file as a single string. Then, without splitting that line into its constituent fields, it passes the string to the CSV writer. As a result, the `csv.writer` will treat the string as a sequence and output each *character* , including any terminating new line character, as a separate field. For example, if your input CSV file contains:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Your output file would be written like this:

```
1,",",2,",",3,",",4,"
"
```

You should change the `for` loop to this:

```
for row in csv.reader(f1):
    # process the row
    wr.writerow(row)
```

Now the input CSV file will be parsed into fields and `row` will contain a list of strings - one for each field. For the previous example, `row` would be:

```
for row in csv.reader(f1):
    print(row)
```

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

And when that list is passed to the `csv.writer` the output to the file will be:

```
1,2,3,4
```

---

Putting all of that together you get this code:

```
import csv

with open('input_1.csv') as f1, open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    for row in csv.reader(f1):
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hi All, Now I getting expected result. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 3):

On Python 3, `csv` *requires* that you open the file in text mode, not binary mode. Drop the `b` from your file mode. You should really use `newline=''` too:

```
resultFile = open("out.csv", "w", newline='')
```

Better still, use the file object as a context manager to ensure it is closed automatically:

```
with open("input_1.csv", "r") as f1, \
     open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    for var in f1:
        wr.writerow([var.rstrip('\n')])
```

I've also *stripped* the lines from `f1` (just to remove the newline) and put the line in a list; `csv.writer.writerow` wants a sequence with columns, not a single string.

Quoting the [`csv.writer()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> If *csvfile* is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''` [1]. *[...]* All other non-string data are stringified with `str()` before being written.
>
> [1] If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module does its own ([universal](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)) newline handling.

Comment: Typically newline is required on windows or you have blank lines inserted after each lines because of the added CR chars

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: and for any other platform where `\n` is not the default newline character (as the `\n` character is going to be replaced on any of those).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I used newline but getting each letter is separate column

Comment: @krish: updated; you can't pass in a single string, as that'll be seen as a row with columns (each letter a separate column). I've put it in a *list* here.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: thanks, now getting expected result :)

Answer (score 0):

open file without b mode

b mode open your file as binary

you can open file as w

```
open_file = open("filename.csv", "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the input file in normal read mode but the output file is opened in binary mode, correct way

```
resultFile = open("out.csv", "w")
```

As shown above if you replace "wb" with "w" it will work.

Comment: While opening without b, I getting one row blank in result file.